# Term for both debit and credit

Tags: accounting

This is a vocabulary question: What English term could be used to represent something that is either a debit or a credit in a transaction (without specifically saying which one it is)?

Something like "ledger entry", but "ledger entry" is too vague.

Comment: Why would you wish to specifically exclude whether the transaction is a debit or a credit?

Comment: I'm looking for a generic term. Same reason people use the word "Person" instead of always specifying "man" or "woman".

Comment: Then I don't follow why "ledger entry" is too vague...

Answer (score 1):

From a generic database point of view, we would call them transactions which have a type of debit or credit.

From an accounting point of view, there is this [answer on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/is-there-a-hypernym-for-debit-credit)

Comment: I would actually consider a transaction a set of several debits and credits (i.e. a transaction is generally a debit *plus* a credit)

Comment: But from a banking point of view a transaction is either a credit or a debit, one item of processing

Comment: True, but from a double-entry accounting point of view, a credit on your bank account is matched with a debit on an expense account (http://accountrain.com/debit_credit.html).

Comment: Ah OK ... wasnt sure what direction your question was aimed at ... sorry database programmer hat on ... ;0 ... dont really have an accounting hat. I've updated my answer a bit